# c++の配列の初期化方法

Tags: c++

char配列の宣言時に

```
char buf[3] {};
```

としているコードを見ました。

自分の中では

```
char buf[3] = {0};
```

などだと思うのですが、実行結果を見てみるとどちらの方法もゼロで3バイト分埋まっています。

c++的に正しいコードなんでしょうか？
コンパイラはgcc 4.4.7です。

Answer (score 1):

何を持って「正しい」と呼ぶか次第なところがありますが・・・

この記述は [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) で導入された「初期化子リスト」構文です。
https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/initializer_lists.html
- 波括弧 `{ }` が空でも良い
- 直接初期化では `=` を書かない（ここで `=` を書くとコピー初期化になる）
あたりが昔からの [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ユーザーには違和感があるところでしょうか。

よって [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) ではこの初期化子リストは使えません。

オイラの手元のワンチップマイコン開発環境で [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) に対応しているものは皆無なので、その意味でこの書き方は使えない書き方＝正しくない、ということになります。同様、比較的新しい gcc では正しい書き方と言うことになります。

gcc-7.1.0 ではこんな挙動を示しました。

```
$ g++ -c cpp11init.cpp # 無警告でコンパイルできた
$ g++ -c -std=c++03 cppinit.cpp
cppinit.cpp:3:16: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   char buf[3]{};
              ^
$
```

gcc-4.9.4 では `g++ -c cpp11init.cpp` で警告発生
`g++ -c -std=c++11 cpp11init.cpp` で警告なしとなりました。

何年付けの [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 言語仕様書をベースにして話するかで正しくも誤りでもあります。話の前提条件の段階で [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) や [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) など規格書を指定する必要があるんでしょうね。

Comment: コンパイラのバージョンだけ書いておいて、情報の提示が不足していました。オプションとして,-std=c++0xを付けてコンパイルしていましたので、c++11であると言う前提で正しい構文であるという事ですね。

Comment: `-std=c++0x` は `-std=c++11` のエイリアスですからそのとおりですね。